# What was the age of Adaline Bowman's daughter in The Age of Adaline?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-age-of-adaline

I was rewatching *The Age of Adaline* and I got a little bit confused. What's the age of Adaline Bowman's daughter Flemming Prescott in the movie? She is aging normally and we eventually see her age ahead of her mother. The Narrator does mention Adaline doesn't age for the next 60 or 70 years. By that estimate wouldn't her daughter have already died?

Answer (score 4):

The actress playing her daughter is [Ellen Burstyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellen_Burstyn), who is (currently) 83 herself. Considering that Adeline's daughter was only a few years old at the time of the accident that caused Adaline's "condition", I don't see how her being in her eighties (or even nineties) would be that extraordinary.

Answer (score 3):

According to this clip of the [movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UzSekc0LoQ), Adaline was born January 1, 1908, and Flemming was born in 1935, which would make them 27 years apart.  My understanding is that Adaline had her accident in 1937, shortly after Flemming's birth, which made her an "eternal" 29.

From 1935 to the end of 2015 would be 80 years. Not everyone lives that long, but given Adaline's "longevity," it's not unlikely that Flemming would enjoy the same.

Comment: This is a good answer except for the last sentence: *"given Adaline's "longevity," it's not unlikely that Flemming would enjoy the same"* - Adaline's unnatural longevity was due to the lightning strike that happened well after Flemming was born, not any sort of genetic gift, so there's no reason why it would connect with her daughter's longevity at all.